# What is four bytes in png after each section

Tags: image, png, decoding

I'm trying to figure out the PNG format using the following image as an example:

[image]

A different PNG image's hex representation looks like this:

[image]

Between the sections IHDR-sRGB (0f d8 e5 b7 00 00 00 01) and PLTE-IDAT (01 a3 15 58 00 00 00 0c) we have 8 bytes each. If we assume that among these four are the CRC bytes, then what are the other four bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each chunk is a four-byte length, a four-byte ID, the data, and four-byte CRC. So your IHDR chunk CRC is `0f d8 e5 b7`, and the next four bytes, `00 00 00 01` is the length of the data content of the sRGB chunk.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#5Chunk-layout